# Why does Eclipse think I'm typing "ctrl+a" when I'm only typing "a"?

Tags: fedora, eclipse

I currently using Eclipse with Fedora 16, everything is perfect before I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to search a file.

In the file search tab:

- When I type 'a' Eclipse seems to get a 'ctrl + a'
- So I cannot type an 'a' for searching

But in the editor everything is ok!

Before I type 'a':

[image: befor i type 'a']

After I type 'a':

[image: after i type 'a']

But when I click the file search in toolbar, I can type everything.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to hit this in the past that actually my keyboard is not in very good condition, the Ctrl key seems stucked down the keyboard until i hit it again. If that is not your scenario, try check if Universal Access -> Sticky Key option in Fedora 16 should you had pressed Ctrl key long enough.

Comment: I think that is not what i suffer from,actually i have replaced a new keyboard last day. And it still appears.

Comment: Ok, verified again and logged a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368313

Comment: I update my fedora and this problem seems fixed.

Comment: good to hear that but if without upgrading to latest GNOME fix, it seems that the problem is coming from GNOME desktop. found this article http://blink4blog.blogspot.com/2012/01/fedora-16-developer-guide-gnome-desktop.html.